# PSQL 9.6 - OR query is much slower on joined table

Tags: postgresql, query, execution-plan, postgresql-9.6, pgadmin

We have a production POSTGRES 9.6 db with about 100M records (LOYALTY) and new table (has just 4 data as of now) "INFO"

**Full index name on table loyalty**

```
indexname "loyalty_activated_at"    colname "activated_at"
indexname "loyalty_created_at"      colname "created_at"
indexname "loyalty_customer_id"     colname "customer_id"
indexname "loyalty_order_id"        colname "order_id"
indexname "loyalty_pkey"            colname "id"
```

**Full index names on table INFO**

```
indexname "info_loyalty_adjustment_id_key" colname "loyalty_adjustment_id"
indexname "info_order_number" colname "order_number"
indexname "info_pkey" colname "id"
indexname "info_restaurant_id"  colname "restaurant_id"
```

#### QUERY 1:

```
explain (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "loyalty"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "info" ON ("loyalty"."id" = "info"."loyalty_adjustment_id")
WHERE ("info"."order_number" = '21072621527905'
    OR "loyalty"."order_id" = 694781500)
```

This yields a slow query: (full scan)

```
Limit  (cost=19.23..120.18 rows=21 width=220) (actual time=53814.148..77814.842 rows=1 loops=1)"
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=19.23..2858123.35 rows=594498 width=220) (actual time=53814.147..77814.840 rows=1 loops=1)"
        Hash Cond: (loyalty.id = info.info_id)"
        Filter: (((info.order_number)::text = '21072621527905'::text) OR (loyalty.order_id = 694781500))"
        Rows Removed by Filter: 118934642"
        ->  Seq Scan on loyalty  (cost=0.00..2412225.44 rows=118899344 width=50) (actual time=1.001..59578.218 rows=118934643 loops=1)"
        ->  Hash  (cost=14.10..14.10 rows=410 width=170) (actual time=0.508..0.508 rows=4 loops=1)"
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
              ->  Seq Scan on info  (cost=0.00..14.10 rows=410 width=170) (actual time=0.500..0.500 rows=4 loops=1)"
Planning time: 1.185 ms"
Execution time: 77814.890 ms"
```

Separating the query into 2 without OR clause makes it much much faster < 1 sec

#### QUERY 2:

```
explain (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "loyalty"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "info" ON ("loyalty"."id" = "info"."loyalty_adjustment_id")
WHERE
    "info"."order_number" = '21072620001657'
```

Query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.57..5.64 rows=1 width=110) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)"
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..5.64 rows=1 width=110) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)"
        ->  Seq Scan on info  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=1 width=60) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)"
              Filter: ((order_number)::text = '21072620001657'::text)"
              Rows Removed by Filter: 4"
        ->  Index Scan using loyalty_pkey on loyalty  (cost=0.57..4.58 rows=1 width=50) (never executed)"
              Index Cond: (id = info.loyalty_adjustment_id)"
Planning time: 0.201 ms"
Execution time: 0.029 ms"
```

AND

#### QUERY 3:

```
explain (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, FORMAT JSON)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "loyalty"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "info" ON ("loyalty"."id" = "info"."loyalty_adjustment_id")
WHERE ("info"."order_number" = '21072620001657'
    AND "loyalty"."order_id" = 4967472)
LIMIT 21
```

Query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.57..5.65 rows=1 width=110) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)"
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..5.65 rows=1 width=110) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=0 loops=1)"
        Join Filter: (loyalty.id = loyalty_loyaltyorderinfo.loyalty_adjustment_id)"
        ->  Index Scan using loyalty_order_id on loyalty  (cost=0.57..4.58 rows=1 width=50) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)"
              Index Cond: (order_id = 4967472)"
        ->  Seq Scan on info  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=1 width=60) (never executed)"
              Filter: ((order_number)::text = '21072620001657'::text)"
Planning time: 0.197 ms"
Execution time: 0.031 ms"
```

---

#### Question

1. Why is having OR clause makes it much much slower than two separate query with union? Especially when INFO table has just 4 records!

Does it have to do anything with having condition on BOTH tables?

2. QUERY 2, it seems like it is doing a full table scan on INFO because INFO table have only so little data (<10) as of now.

The part where index scan is not executed because of so few data:

```
Index Scan using loyalty_pkey on loyalty  (cost=0.57..4.58 rows=1 width=50) (never executed)"
              Index Cond: (id = info.loyalty_adjustment_id)"
```

If this was to run, why is not doing anything better than full index scan (index range scan or better) since it is looking for a SINGLE value only?

i.e. "info"."order_number" = '21072620001657'

Comment: With the `OR` operator in the search predicate you cannot eliminate any rows until you join both tables in their entirety. Sequential scan is usually the fastest way to read the entire table.